# Can I (re)map Ex commands in vim?

Tags: vim

I love vim and the speed it gives me. But sometimes, my fingers are too speedy and I find myself typing `:WQ` instead of `:wq`. (On a German keyboard, you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get the colon `:`.) Vim will then complain that `WQ` is `Not an editor command`.

Is there some way to make `W` and `Q` editor commands?

Comment: You use shift to get a colon on a standard American QWERTY too.

Comment: Shouldn't that be on Superuser?

Comment: you can also map ; (or whatever is on the : key) to : and vice versa so you don't need to use shift  to get the :.

Comment: ; by default jumps to the next instance of a character that you found using f (similar to how n find the next instance of a / search).  If you decide to remap it, you lose that functionality.

Comment: @AnthonyDiSanti not if you remap `;` back to `:`! `noremap ; :` `noremap : ;` :P

Comment: There is a similar question in Vi Stackexchange: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2665/7244

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try

```
 :command WQ wq
 :command Wq wq
 :command W w
 :command Q q
```

This way you can define your own commands. See `:help command` for more information.

Comment: don't forget to add the above to your vimrc so you don't have to do it every time.

Comment: Note that in .vimrc, you need to omit the leading colon. It should read, for example: `command Wq wq`

Comment: This solution is limited to a command names that begin with capitol letters.   A much better solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879737/1519199).

Comment: This does not let you use arguments, for instance, `:W example.txt` will fail to work if you set up the alias using `:command W w`

Comment: Using vim `8.0.1453`, in my `.vimrc`, I had to use `cmap WQ wq`, not "command".  Vim gave me `E128: Invalid command name` otherwise.

Answer (score 39):

Alternative way to do it:

Use '[command abbreviations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#Abbreviations)'

```
:ca WQ wq
```

Comment: A helpful way to remember that: The full keyword is `cabbrev`. :)

Comment: +1 This also allows for aliases starting with a lower case letter (in contrast to `:command`).

Comment: This solution will replace `WQ` where ever it is in the command, not just at the beginning, which might be rare for 'WQ' but nor for more commonly typed strings.  Hence, [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879737/1519199) is better.

Answer (score 17):

And you can use

```
:cmap WQ wq
```

as well.
E.g. I have

```
cmap h tab help
```

in my `.vimrc` which means opening help pages in a new tab.

[Thanks for the tip Jim Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117150/can-i-re-map-commands-in-vim/119821#comment18676583_119821):

> But here is a much better solution as the above (for the help mapping,
>   so that it only applies when you do :h):
>
> ```
> cnoreabbrev <expr> h getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "h" ? "tab h" : "h"
> ```

Comment: On which version if (G)Vim?

What happens, when you type '<ESC>:cmap h tab help<CR>:h<SPACE>'?

Comment: -1: touches far too much. For example, `:echo 3` will then produce `:ectab helpo 3`. `:e sh.py` becomes `:e stab help.py`. Et cetera.

Comment: This is off-topic, but you probably want something like `cnoreabbrev <expr> h getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "h" ? "tab h" : "h"` for the help mapping, so that it only applies when you do `:h<space>`.

Comment: Thank you @JimStewart it is a much better solution, I will add it to my answer!

Comment: :cmap h tab help makes vim output tab all over the screen in a forever loop.

Comment: helped me using `:cnoreabbrev ص w` override `:w` command to be available in Persian ;) thanks