# Why does `:Wq` in VIM cause my commit to fail later?

Tags: git, vim, commit, git-commit

Often when I'm finished writing a commit message in VIM, I type `:Wq<ENTER>` instead of `:wq<ENTER>` because I'm holding down the shift key to type the colon. This causes VIM to respond with `E492: Not an editor command: Wq`.

This is all fine so far, I just retype `:wq<ENTER>` to save the commit message and exit VIM. However, the commit does not work then, and the terminal shows something like this:

```
$ git commit
$ error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
$ Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Why does accidentally entering `:Wq<ENTER>` before doing the correct `:wq<ENTER>` cause the commit to fail? Is there any way to get the commit to happen after entering `:Wq<ENTER>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://tooky.co.uk/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x/) seems to describe a similar issue.

Looks like when you use the capital 'W' Vim is exiting with an error code when invoked by Git.

Have you tried:

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

(or wherever you have vim installed on your system)...which seemed to clear up the issue. Must be related to how how Git invokes Vim.

Also, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/why-would-vim-return-non-zero-exit-code-if-i-exit-immediately-after-opening) which indicates that it may have to do with the `filetype` setting.

Comment: This seems to be getting close to the issue: if `core.editor` is set to `/usr/bin/vi`I get the error described in my OP, whereas if it's set to `/usr/bin/vim`things work correctly. It's weird though, because `/usr/bin/vi` is just a symlink to `/usr/bin/vim`

Comment: Still a little curious on the "why" but this fixes things for me, so I'm going to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't replicate this issue. That is, I was able to get the `E492: Not an editor command: Wq` error, but running `:wq` afterwards successfully closed **vim** and saved the commit.

Perhaps you can try something similar to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/117221/864233

```
:command WQ wq
:command Wq wq
:command W w
:command Q q
```

Save those four "aliases" to a file in `~/.vimrc` and if you accidentally run `:Wq` again, it won't error out on you.

Also, as **Jonathan.Brink** noted above, make sure you're actually using **vim** and not **vi**, as that may be causing some issues as well.

Comment: On my machine (OSX), `/usr/bin/vi` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/vim`, so git is using VIM here. Agreed that aliases could fix the issue, thanks for the suggestion! Just curious to why it's happening also :)